# How to access all calendar shared with me?

Tags: outlook, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I am building an application for users to access their calendars over multiple providers. I have an integration with Office 365 using the Graph API.
I currently use delegated permissions and the `/me/calendars` endpoint to fetch the data.

This works fine for personal calendars created inside outlook, but it does not work well for shared and external calendars. My goal is that the calendars (and events) that the user sees in the native outlook interface are the same that the user sees in my app.

As far as I am aware, these are the various ways that a calendar can be shared in the Microsoft ecosystem:

1. **Explicit user share**

   - Permission: `Calendar.Read`
   - If the Owner explicitly shares a calendar with another user it will appear in `/me/calendars`
   - That is perfect for me, but most users don't do that
2. **Implicit organization share**

   - Permission: `Calendar.Read`
   - By default all members of the organization can see the free/busy of other members. Users add them via the `Add from directory` tab in outlook.
   - This allows us to query `/me/calendar/getschedule` with a list of users to get some events
   - This is problematic because I do not know which members my user "follows" in outlook
3. **Explicit organization share**

   - Permission: `Calendar.Read.Shared`
   - If the Owner changes the sharing to `can view all details` then we can access `/users/{USER_ID}/calendars`
   - This is again problematic because I do not know which members my user "follows" in outlook and it requires a manual step by other members
4. **Group calendar**

   - Permission: `Group.Read.All`
   - This allows access to `/group/{GROUP_ID}/calendar`
   - This is once more problematic because I do not know which groups my user "follows" in outlook
5. **External calendar**

   - No idea how to access those, they don't show up in `/me/calendars`

So my question is: Did I miss something that would allow all those various calendars to show up in a single unified API call (preferably in `/me/calendars`)? Otherwise, is it possible to know which calendars my user "follows" on outlook?

At the end of the day, my users don't care how the calendar was shared with them on outlook but they do complain if one calendar (say in `People's calendars` group) is not showing up in my app. The documentation on shared calendars is quite lacking and I reviewed all other SO posts without much luck.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, here you go. You can get it started with these two Microsoft documentations, which talks about in-detail how you can access shared mailboxes, permissions you need etc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-shared-events-calendars, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-create-event-in-shared-delegated-calendar?tabs=http!!

Comment: For example, I logged in as Megan, get all the events in the primary calendar that Alex has shared with Megan, directly from Alex' mailbox, then i will make Graph API call - "GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{Alex-userId | Alex-userPrincipalName}/calendar/events". On successful completion, you'll get HTTP 200 OK and a collection of event instances in Alex' primary calendar, directly from Alex' mailbox. If Alex has not shared nor delegated his primary calendar with Megan, specifying Alex’s user ID or user principal name in the preceding GET operations will return an error.

Comment: I already knew about this sharing but it is at best incomplete. It doesnt seem possible to have a unified view of my calendars like outlook, I am not sure what was the thought process that lead to that decision. Especially when you compare that to google where what you see in the calendar is what you get in the api.

Comment: If you talk about API perspective, definitely it pulls you the data what you look for and it does its work, even complex shared calendar scenarios. If you have suggestions on Microsoft to improve the feature, feel free to raise a Microsoft uservoice - so that they can consider implementing it. Here's the closest uservoice that i can find - https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/36131674-create-microsoft-graph-subscriptions-for-a-shared. You may want to spin up your new feature requests here.

Comment: The problem with all the given examples is that it assumes you know that megan has shared the calendar. If I am an external application how can I retrieve that information without enumerating all the people in the organization? In Google, I know that if the user subscribe to a calendar I will get it in my request but it is not the case in microsoft.

Comment: Cool, interesting view. As i said above, if you look for more information or Microsoft to implement in you can file a documentation bug or file uservoice to get more samples (as you described above) and see if they can able to do the same.

Comment: @Sytten Did you ever get an answer / workaround for this problem?

Comment: No I don't believe this is possible with the current APIs and I don't work the problem anymore. IMO this is just bad API design from microsoft compared to the API offered by google and should be improved but since we were not a multi-million partner they would not help us.

Comment: i was shocked to find list calendards doesn't list shared calendars, and there is no list shared calendars